# Bug in Custom Searches - Date Added to CiviCRM

Tags: database

I'm fairly new to CiviCRM but have successfully imported over 3,100 contacts from our current PC based DB system. If an error occurs during the my imports I have found the Custom Search 'Date Added to CiviCRM' invaluable! However, when I try to exclude imported contacts that had been previously successfully grouped the search fails (returns nothing). The search is conducted on contacts that have all been imported on the same day which is also the current day.  Could it be that the group exclusion feature only works on prior day's work or is this a bug? I'm using version 4.7.10

Sincerely,
Mike Samyn - San Diego

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail, perhaps a screen-shot, to show _exactly_ what the criteria are on the search that returns no records?

Comment: In addition to Joe's question, could you also indicate whether you are attempting to use the include/exclude search with smart groups and/or nested groups?

Comment: I'm very sorry but I can not duplicate the problem now.  I was importing contacts on top of some manually entered contacts I had entered earlier in that same day with a special Group I have now removed.  Testing prior dated entries things seem to work. I'll try testing this condition again and reply back.

Comment: Alas It will not repeat.  I know back then it was not using the latest version of CiviCRM.  I'm fully up to date now.  Regrets - Mike